# While loop executes once during return, runs fine during print [python]

Tags: python, printing, while-loop, return

I have two functions I'm using. I'm trying to make a bifurcation map. The first function I have is making the map using matplotlib.

```
def print_bifurcation_map(initial,rmin,rmax,rstep,iterates,k):
    xn_list = []
    r_list = []

    for r in np.linspace(rmin, rmax,rstep):
        xn = []
        xn.append(run_logistic(initial,r,iterates))
        xn_list =xn_list + xn[-k:]


        r_list = r_list + [r]*len(xn)
```

What this code does is take a range of Rs and calculates the limit as x approaches a large number (iterates). We take the last k numbers from the list. It calls a function run_logistic which is below.

```
def run_logistic(xn,r,iterates):
    iteration = 1
    while iteration <= iterates:
        xn1 = logistic_map(xn,r)
        iteration = iteration + 1
        xn = xn1
        print xn
```

Here is where things get a little weird. when I use return and call through the function 'print_bifurcation_map' it runs once and appends once. However if I i change return xn to the 'print xn' which is what is in the code block now it seems to run more correctly albeit very very slowly.

So what am I doing incorrectly in either the print_bifurcation_map definition or the run_logistic function. Below is the logistic_map function.

```
def logistic_map(xn,r):
    xn1 = r*xn*(1-xn)
    return xn1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return exits the function at that point and outputs the returned value. So after the first iteration your value is returned at then it's done.

What are you trying to do with the function `run_logistic` return a final value or all values obtained?

If you want the final value then -

```
def run_logistic(xn,r,iterates):
    iteration = 1
    while iteration <= iterates:
        xn1 = logistic_map(xn,r)
        iteration = iteration + 1
        xn = xn1
    return xn # Put return outside while-loop to get final value
```

Otherwise if you want all values then create a list to append to and return that list

```
def run_logistic(xn,r,iterates):
    iteration = 1
    xn_list = []
    while iteration <= iterates:
        xn1 = logistic_map(xn,r)
        iteration = iteration + 1
        xn = xn1
        xn_list.append(xn)
    return xn_list # Put return outside while-loop to get full list of values
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I did not realize that return exits the function. I need all values of xn_list for this one, so I'm going to have to return an appended list. thanks for your help.